# What is the difference between these two half bridge configurations?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I have seen two different half bridge versions.

One has an extra capacitor attached between the load and the neutral point of the capacitor divider.

What is the difference?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first circuit looks like a series resonant topology, probably trying to use the leakage inductance of the transformer as part of the resonant circuit.  Similar to an LLC, but hard to say exactly because we can't see the control scheme.

The advantages are higher efficiency due to soft switching, and the disadvantage is more complex control.

From the EETimes article [here:](https://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1273871#)

[image]

The second circuit is a conventional half-bridge.

Comment: I have seen the both topologies in half bridge SMPS using the same controller chip that is TL494

Comment: @ASWINVENU That's a very old part with some basic building blocks in it that could be used for a fixed PWM or resonant scheme.  The details would be in the schematic and implementation.